# UltraMonthViewSingle appointments overlaps after increasing it's height

Tags: winforms, height, infragistics, overlap, appointment

Its about appointments' height in Infragistic's UltraMonthViewSingle control. In my code, it overlaps appointment in single day after increasing height of it using CreationFilter. So for more, can you look into this link please.

[http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/86148/429648.aspx#429648][1]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> An appointments on UltraMonthViewSingle overlaps each other since i
>   have increased the height. Can you modify this creation filter in
>   order to remove unnecessary overlapping of appointment or Can you
>   write another one which can work for me?

The mentioned behavior is expected, because when you increate the height of your first appointment, you didn`t change the Y location of your second appointment. In your scenario you should modify your code (for example Rectangle(editor.Rect.X, editor.Rect.Y, editor.Rect.Width, 35) ) and add additional value to Rect.Y depending of number of your current appointment per day

> I want to have non-bold text on every appointment in UltraDayView for
>   both Day view and Work Week View. Is it possible?

There are different approaches to solve this task. Maybe the easiest way could be if you are using AppStyle  with desired look and feel.  Another possible approach could be if you change VliewStyle of your UltraCalendarLook. The third option could be if you implement DrawFilter.

Let me know if you have any questions.